# Node titles as select list in views

Tags: drupal, view, title, selectlist

I Have two content types.

School

```
Title (name of school)
location (geolocation - geofield)
```

User Properties (students)

```
school (entity reference)
class
```

Now I want to filter every school by title in a view  as Exposed Filter. How can I display all names as select list? The filter works perfectly by typing the name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Views Reference Filter module should do what you are looking for.

Alternatively you create the select list in a hook_form_alter on the view exposed filter form.